# How can I make links to pictures instead of embedded pictures?

Tags: libreoffice

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS with LibreOffice 4.2.7.2.
When I use HTML writer and I want insert a picture, LibreOffice generates a html page with embedded picture, but I want get a link to the picture.
At the menu insert file there is shown a checkbox insert as link, but I can not set or reset the value.

Comment: How should the link look like? A test link or some sort of thumbnail?